# radio button show only if collection is greater than 1,rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using radio button to show collection of record but here I want that when collection is equal to one than I want to hide radio button..
Here I'm using

```
-if collection.count > 1
  = t.input :sibling_parent,  :as => :radio, :collection => @sibling_parents_drop, :input_html => {:class=>"ml", :checked => 'checked'}
-else
  %h2
   field without radio button
```

But it doesn't work for me .Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- if @sibling_parents_drop.count > 1`